# Sync data options between Windows 8 and Phone 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, synchronization

I would like to create an app where the user can add and view data. Either adding at a desktop/tablet or phone and reading from either source. I would like the data store to be synced between any of the user's devices.

I'm starting to play with the Trial of Azure, and it looks promising. Probably a solid way to sync data through to cloud between users' devices. Other than syncing between a users devices, I have no need for cloud services currently.

I've seen some apps that do a 'Backup/Restore' model with the user's SkyDrive account. But this seems to be a manual process. I'd like to see it done seamlessly.

I've looked into Sync services, but that would be more like a hub/spoke solution. Again, I don't need a central database.

What are some options? At this point, I would be fine using just Windows 8 patterns/practices.

Comment: should you decide on a database solution check out: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/lex-db-a-new-database-storage-solution-for-windows-phone-8/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+qmatteoq_eng+%28qmatteoq.com%29&utm_content=Google+Reade

Answer (score 3):

Because they are separate devices, you will need to have some service layer to do the store/forward for you.  With that you have two basic choices, use the end user's own storage (aka SkyDrive) or use your own storage (aka Windows Azure).

SkyDrive is fully supported through the [Live SDKs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521) and provides a secure way to allow a user to share store their data, and synchronize it across multiple devices.  You get security, and there is no cost for the server side storage on your part.  The user owns their storage, not you. The limitation is that you may have issues sharing that same data across other devices or users where SkyDrive (or whatever file sync service you use) is not available.

With a service layer, like Azure, you have a lot more flexibility, but you also will be responsible for maintaining (and paying for) that server side storage / services.  Have you looked at "[Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/)".  With your Azure account you get 10 free Azure Mobile Services.  You will pay for the SQL data storage on the backend, and that cost will depend on the amount of data you store on the server side. You also need to make sure to architect your application in a way to protect an individual users' data, but it is actually pretty easy to do, well documented, and gives you a lot of options.

Lastly, you may consider what type of data you want to share.  SkyDrive is great for "Files". Pics, Songs, Videos, etc. Windows Azure Mobile Services (WAMS) is great for "Data".

Neither model is right or wrong.  It just depends on your goals.

Hope that helps you go through the thought process

Comment: It looks like SkyDrive would be the way to go. I don't need the data. It's the users data. However, I was looking at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/live/hh826521
I saw this:
Here are some examples of nonconforming apps:
Apps that automatically upload to SkyDrive any file added to a specific location on a user’s devices.

This kind of is what I wanted to do, let the app save the file and read it.